# i cant see the whole html element

Tags: html, css

i have two divs

first div : text-logo

```css
.text-logo {
            width: 250px;
            height: 60px;
          margin: auto;
            border: 2px solid #07a2a0;
            border-radius: 15px  50px  15px 50px;
    margin-top: 100px;
   

    
          }
```

```html
         <div class="text-logo"><h4>Just training/cit</h4></div>
```

second div : image-logo

```css
.image-logo { overflow: hidden; height: 500px;}
.image-logo .left 
{ 
    float: left ;
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
}

.image-logo .right
{
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

.image-logo .left img
{
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;

}
```

```html
   <div class="image-logo">
                    
                    <div class="left">                    
                        <img src="images/logo.png">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="right">
                      <h2>Being auomated much more easy than the manual things
                      </h2>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
```

i cant see the blue logo with the original size, the upper part of the logo is hidden ,

[image]

the picture will show you the problem

,

Answer (score 1):

Try to add z-index

```
.image-logo .left img
{
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index:2;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the div `.text-logo` is above your logo div. You should change the `z-index` of one of them. It defines which element should be above another element. Use for your `z-index` a realistic value, to keep your code a bit cleaner.

```
  .image-logo .left img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index:5; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the element's `color` is not the same as the `background color`, as that will obviously make you not to see your element.

I have been a victim of this severally. Hope it helps someone.